# Is there a way of estimating progress of A* finding a path?

Tags: algorithm, graph, progress, a-star, estimation

Finding a shortest path in a quite large graph may take a while. A long while in some cases even. From what I know about [the algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) it's impossible to tell exactly how many nodes A* needs to visit to find a shortest path but maybe there is at least a way of estimating it along the way?

This would be to give at least an approximation of progress to the user, but I'd guess it's quite hard to do so in a good way.

Comment: If you had a 'perfect estimation' (`h*`) you would not need A* - greedy best first will yield an optimal result. The fact is your estimation is actually dependent on your heuristic - the better (more informed) it is - the better approximation it gives, and `h*` gives a perfect estimation.

Comment: what does "large graph" mean? you can handle millions of node in less than 100ms like I've done it with graphhopper. Debugging your algorithm is also possible with it: http://karussell.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/astar.gif

Answer (score 1):

Using the smallest `EstimatedDistanceToEnd` (ie. `h(x)`) seen so far would be an estimate, but not necessarily a good one.

Perhaps you should look into [ways of speeding up](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14753/how-can-i-make-my-a-algorithm-faster) your algorithm, or look into using a [faster](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32813/how-does-dwarf-fortress-keep-track-of-so-many-entities-without-losing-performanc/32831#32831) and/or [approximate](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ggordon/likhachev-etal.anytime-dstar.pdf) algorithm?

Comment: I would guess that is the current estimate (at least the progress currently makes large jumps in the beginning and then stalls around 90 %). But the heuristic is probably a little off anyway since it only considers Euclidian distance whereas all paths are weighted differently. Finding a better heuristic might not be easy either ;)